# Got an error trying to install mod_v8 for FreeSwitch 10 in Debian 11: You need to either install libv8-6.1-dev, ibv8fs-dev

Tags: javascript, debian, v8, freeswitch

On a "clean" Debian 11, I deployed all the necessary packages and began to build FreeSWITCH 10 with the mod_v8 module enabled.

When executing the `./configure` command, I get the message:

```
checking for v8-6.1_static >= 6.1.298...
checking for v8fs_static >= 6.1.298...
checking for v8 >= 6.1.298...
configure: error: You need to either install **libv8-6.1-dev** (>= 6.1.298), **libv8fs-dev** (>= 6.1.298) or disable mod_v8 in modules.conf
```

There are no packages named **libv8-6.1-dev** and **libv8fs-devlibv8fs-dev** in Debian 11.
I was looking for packages in Debian 11 that contain *v8*, with the command `search v8` and installed all the packages found that mention *v8* and *JavaScript*:

```
libv8-dev libnode-dev libnode72 node-babel7-standalone node-clean-css node-get-caller-file node-nan node-to-fast-properties node-v8flags nodejs
```

I also installed **libv8 packages** which are mentioned here: https://lists.freeswitch.org/pipermail/freeswitch-users/2021-July/134874.html
But I still get the error message.

What packages do I need to install? Is there a command that will help me find the names of the necessary packages that contain: ***libv8-6.1-dev** (>= 6.1.298), **libv8fs-dev** (>= 6.1.298)*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The procedure for installing mod_v8 on Debian 11.**

1. Download and install deb packages from here (registration required):
   https://freeswitch.signalwire.com/repo/deb/freeswitch-1.8/pool/main/libv/
2. Install the downloaded packages with the command:
   `sudo apt install -y ./package_name.deb`

List of packages (some may not install):

libv8-6.1_6.1.298-1_bullseye_amd64.deb

libv8-6.1_6.1.298-1_buster_amd64.deb

libv8-6.1_6.1.298-1_stretch_amd64.deb

libv8-6.1-dbg_6.1.298-1_bullseye_amd64.deb

libv8-6.1-dbg_6.1.298-1_buster_amd64.deb

libv8-6.1-dbg_6.1.298-1_stretch_amd64.deb

libv8-6.1-dev_6.1.298-1_bullseye_amd64.deb

libv8-6.1-dev_6.1.298-1_buster_amd64.deb

libv8-6.1-dev_6.1.298-1_stretch_amd64.deb

libv8fs-6.1_6.1.298-1_stretch_amd64.deb

libv8fs-6.1-dbg_6.1.298-1_stretch_amd64.deb

libv8fs-6.1-dev_6.1.298-1_stretch_amd64.deb

3. If FreeSWITCH is already installed, then you need to uncomment along the path:
   `/usr/local/freeswitch/conf/autoload_configs`
   in the file:
   `modules.conf.xml`
   line:
   `load module="mod_v8"`
   Then install only mod_v8 via (run from the FreeSWITCH build folder): `make mod_v8-install`
4. If FREESWITCH not installed, then enable mod_v8 in the `modules.conf` file in the freeswitch (or freeswitch-master) folder from which the build will be made.
5. Finally, in the FreeSWITCH console, run the `load mod_v8` command (the answer must be True).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try install from the website?

https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libv8-dev

There is a download link

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!
Should I install this package manually? When I try to install "libv8-dev" via "apt-get" in the console, I get a message that "libnode-dev" will be installed instead (this package is also installed, the latest version). And here: https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/libv8-3.14 the message about "libv8-dev" is that "This package is not in any development repository. This probably means that the package has been deleted (or renamed)."

Comment: Try to install it manually with the link I've send above you should be able to find the other dependencies :)

Comment: When FreeSWITCH needs V8 >= 6.1, then libv8-3.14.5.8 (from all the way back in 2013!) isn't going to help.

Answer (score 0):

The [mailing list conversation you linked](https://lists.freeswitch.org/pipermail/freeswitch-users/2021-July/134874.html) also contains this snippet:

> You should try building libv8 packages from here: https://github.com/freeswitch/libv8-packaging

I'd try that.

It doesn't look like Debian has ever had an official `libv8-6.1-dev` package, or at least I can't find any traces of it. It definitely doesn't offer one now.

(The whole thing does seem a bit sketchy; [that build script](https://github.com/freeswitch/libv8-packaging/blob/master/linux/Makefile) uses V8 6.1.298, which is a random daily snapshot from mid-2017; but hey, as long as it never touches possibly-attacker-controlled scripts or input data, I guess it's fine... who needs production-quality releases in their production setups, eh?
You could try to at least switch to the tip of the stabilized 6.1 branch, which would be the `6.1.534.44` tag (a.k.a. `branch-heads/6.1`), but (1) that also hasn't received any further fixes for five years now, and (2) if you're already having trouble getting things to work, then any deviation from workflows that are said to have worked before only increases the risk of further trouble.)